# Gnuplot different colors inside newhistogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I am plotting a histogram rowstacked very similar to this graph (the last one on [this page](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html)) :

[image]

What I would like to do is to have different colors for each year bin. This colors would repeat from a newhistogram to another. I have not yet found a way to do this.

An example with my data of what I am trying to accomplish is

[image: here]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So instead of 8 colors you want 8*8 colors? That doesn't seem like good graphic design.What extra value would that add to the above graph? (Sorry to go philisophical on you), just MHO, you're free to disregard ;-) ) Or you need to dummy up 1 bin with your color scheme so we can visually understand your goal. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter In my dataset I do not have as many colors as here. I only have 2 bars per newhistogram and 2 colors per bar. So this would make for 4 different colors. I will post an image with my exact plot.

Comment: @shellter I have added an image with the result that I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is your actual problem with this? Using the `histograms` plotting should work fine. Consider the following data file

```
A -1 1 -0.5 0.5
B -2 2 -1   1
C -3 3 -1.5 1.5
D -4 4 -2   2
E -5 5 -2.5 2.5
F -4 4 -2   2
G -3 3 -1.5 1.5
```

which you can plot with

```
set key tmargin horizontal
set style fill solid noborder
set style data histograms
set style histogram gap 1
plot 'data.dat' using 2:xtic(1) title "First",\
     '' using 4 title "Second",\
     newhistogram at 0,\
     '' using 3 title "Third",\
     '' using 5 title "Fourth"
```

The result is

[image]

Here, I explicitely assume, that in one column you have only negative or only positive values. But that isn't necessary in general. All further fine-tuning depends on your actual data file format, and other, unknown, conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me solve my problem. The problem I was having was using 

plot newhistogram, 'data.dat' using 2: [...]

Because of the use of that first newhistogram everything was getting wierd.

Comment: I have tried using this with all positive data, but they don<t get stacked ont on top of each other. They get plotted over. Is it possible to use all positive values and put the violet and green under the blue and orange?

Comment: Well, my answer was very specific to the example image you gave. Without having any data of your specific use case, how should I know what you have and what you want?!

Comment: The main problem here is, that you cannot mix the histogram style `rowstacked` (as it would be required to stack the values), and the `clustered` style (to have columns between each other). In this specific solution I solved that by plotting one histogram for negative values, and a new histogram for the positive values. With the side effect, that boxes don't stack if both values are positive. In order to construct such a plot you'll probably need to misuse the `boxxyerrorbars` style.